# Sending pictures using Bluetooth connection (devices already paired)

Tags: android, image, bluetooth

I've been working on this part of my project for several days but I still can't figure out what it's wrong with it. I just want to send a picture from a phone to another, using Bluetooth. I don't need to search for devices or to pair any device in the app. The devices will be paired before the launching of each app.

I'm using this code : https://kamrana.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/sending-images-over-bluetooth-in-android/

The sending app seems to be ok but the app which aims to receive the pictures does not work. The activity is always entirely white. It seems that the layout can't be displayed because even when I add TextView in it, they don't appear. The error should be in the class AcceptData but I don't find where...

I have the bluetooth permission in my manifest.